# Spring State machine - reuse Submachine

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have difficulty in re-using a sub-machine diagram.

I have a need to Re-Use one State machine that I have linked to a state as a sub-machine, in another state as a sub-machine. But when I give the reference to it I get a null pointer exception.

Refer image

[image]

I Have added a submachine reference to GeneralTopup, I want to add the same to Register. But it seems impossible. Is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not work as you need to have unique states in a whole machine and this would add same state multiple times. Having said that, it is a story what has been in my mind for a long time but I don't yet know how to implement it.

Comment: Is this issue still applicable today in 2.1.3? We have a similar problem that involves reusing the same sub-machine reference in two state machines. I'm working on providing a small reproducible sample.

Comment: I have created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/801 for my problem.